# Ionic3 cordova emulate android

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I've developed an app on ionic 3, i've tried to test it on android emulator, no errors were shown but app doesn't open it shows 'app closed'

use:
ionic cordova platform add android
then:
ionic cordova emulate android
[image: screenshot]

*No errors either on console nor on chrome device inspector
Thanks for your help

Comment: You can try running command `cordova clean android && cordova build android`.

Comment: Same problem :/